# Problem of calculating the residue of a expression (to confirm the result from a paper)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I use Mathematica to confirm a result from a paper which is to calculate the residue of a expression at zero.

The code and result are given below.

Is this residue too complicated for Matheamtia or I used a wrong method ?

Thanks for any suggestions. :)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

m = Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[\[Nu]];

\[CapitalDelta] = Sinh[m h] Sinh[m h0] - Cosh[m h] Cosh[m h0];

\[CapitalXi] = Cosh[m h0] (Sinh[m h] - Sinh[m h0]) - Sinh[m h0] (Cosh[m h] - Cosh[m h0]);

\[CapitalOmega] = (m h (\[CapitalDelta] + Cosh[m h0] Cosh[m y] - 
 Sinh[m h0] Sinh[m y]))/(m h \[CapitalDelta] + m h0 (Cosh[m h0]^2 - Sinh[m h0]^2) + \[CapitalXi]);

u = FullSimplify[up/(t0 s^2) \[CapitalOmega], {0 <= y <= h, 0 <= y0 <= h, \[Nu] > 0}];

Residue[u, {s, 0}]
```

********************************************* pictures of results ******************************************

[image: intermediate variables for convenience]

[image]

Comment: Where's the definition of $\Omega$ **in the article**?

Comment: @xzczd, my mistake, the definition of omega is given in the pictures. thanks :)

Comment: Also, where's the definition of $X_3$?

Comment: `up` is undefined

Comment: `Series` has no trouble expanding at 0, not sure why `Residue` balks at this.

Comment: @xzczd, I have edited to add the definition of X3. Thanks. :)

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks. `up` is just a positive constant.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, `Series` will gives correct? Any method would be OK, as long as it can confirm the result in the paper.

Comment: The definition of $X_2$ is suspicious, why it contains a $t$?

Comment: The `t` in X2 should comes from E^(s*t)as shown in eqution (30) in the first picture.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The output of `Series` seems to be wrong. `SeriesCoefficient[ u Exp[s t], {s, 0, -1}] // Simplify` outputs `-((h up (h - y) (h - 2 h0 + y))/(2 (h - h0) t0 (-1 + Sqrt[1/ν] Sqrt[ν]) ν))`, whose denominator is actually `0` because `ν>0`. `Limit[D[s^2 u Exp[s t], s], s -> 0]` outputs similar incorrect result. I think there may be bug(s).

Comment: Another suspicious thing: there's a `0 <= y0 <= h` condition in `FullSimplify`, what's `y0`? BTW can you give a set of specific `{ν, h0, h, t0, up, y, t}`  for checking?

Comment: @xzczd, I edit the post to include a set of values for variables. It is very strange that `Residue` still doesn't work, but `NResidue` gives a result.

Comment: Could somebody please add a link to the original paper? Also, are @pengfei_guo and Guo Xinxin the same person? Please have [your accounts merged](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) if so.

Comment: @J.M. yes, the same person. In China, gmail often doesn't works well. But I still prefer this ID (Guo Xinxin). I have follow the steps to merge the  two IDs, and it seems I have done this successfully.

Comment: @J.M. here is the link to the paper on [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245063129_Unsteady_unidirectional_flow_of_Bingham_fluid_between_parallel_plates_with_different_given_volume_flow_rate_conditions) Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I suspect the analytic result given by the paper is also incorrect. No matter how high the `WorkingPrecision` is, there's always a small difference (approximately `2.98*10^-7`) between the result of `NResidue` and $Res(0)$ in the article. The following set of parameter will make the difference even clearer: `{ν -> 1/2, h0 -> 1, h -> 3, t0 -> 1/5, up -> 1/5, y -> 1/3, t -> 5}`

Comment: @xzczd, let assume the answer in the paper is wrong, and go back to the original questions (1) why Residue doesn't work even if numeric values are given for all variables? (2) what is more important: can I expect a analytical solution of this residue?

Comment: @xzczd, when `h0 = 0`, this residue simplified to a more reliable  result as show in equation (36) in the picture. This should be more convenient for testing Mathematica results.

Comment: Then what's the definition of $\rho$ in $(36)$?

Comment: It is the fluid density, and can be set to 3598.

Comment: @m_goldberg,@ Yves Klett, @ MarcoB: Thanks for reminding me not to off topic. I have completely restate my problem.

Comment: In this edit, I believe that I have give all the information to reproduce my problem.

Comment: I should say you've made a step backward… you should post the code **text** rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @xzczd As this post off the topic, I think I'd better start a new post [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118642/why-residue-failed-to-reproduce-the-analytical-solution-of-this-residue-in-a-pap) to state my problem in more clear. Thanks for your constant attention. :)